# Bisection method for more than one solution for an equation f(x) = 0

Tags: c, numerical-methods

I have written the code for solving f(x) = 0 by the bisection method. Here I took f(x) = sin(x) - x*cos(x). The equation in the interval of -10 to +10 has multiple solutions, but using my code I only get one solution after that the program falls into an infinite loop.

My code is :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
double f(double x)
{
    return sin(x) - (x * cos(x)); // Dont forget to set the function f(x).
}
int main()
{
    double a, b, c, l, u, x0, x;

    printf("Set the value of lower and upper limit:\n");
    scanf("%lf", &a);
    scanf("%lf", &b);
    if ((f(a) >= 0) && (f(b) < 0))
    {
        c = a;
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }
    else if ((f(a) < 0) && (f(b) > 0))
    {
    }
    else if (f(b) == 0)
    {
        printf("The Root = %lf", b);
    }
    for (x = a; x < b; x += 0.1)
    {
        //setting lower and upper limits
        l = x;
        u = x + 0.1;
        // if a root lies on lower limit
        if (f(l) == 0)
        {
            printf("The Root = %lf", l);
        }
        //the condition for checking bisection method
        else if (f(l) * f(u) < 0)
        {
            int i = 0;
            do
            {
                x0 = (l + u) / 2;
                if (f(x0) >= 0)
                {
                    u = x0;
                    // printf("changed upper limit to %lf\n", u);
                }
                else
                {
                    l = x0;
                    // printf("changed lower limit to %lf\n", l);
                }
                i++;
            } while (fabs(f(x0)) >= 0.0000001);
            printf("the root is %lf and the # steps is %d \n", x0, i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But it can not iterate the outer for loop or it falls onto infinite loop after giving output...
The output that I am getting is,

```
Set the value of lower and upper limit:
-10
10
the root is -7.725252 and the # steps is 22 
^C
```

How do I solve this kind of problem?
Please give some solution.
Thank you.

Comment: this question is not so much about code rather than understanding the limitations of the algorithm you are using. Bisection expects you to bracket the solution within the initial bounds and it can only tell you about one solution

Comment: Please note that with algorithms like the bisection method is usually a good idea to stop the iterations when the interval is smaller than a predetermined size. At some point, `x0`, `l` and `u` will become numerically equivalent.

Comment: Options include: (a) Sample the interval at numerous points to find other segments where function’s sign changes and then apply bisection to such segments. (b) Given f(x) with solution f(r) = 0, construct g(x) = f(x) / (x-r). Then g might be non-zero at r, and a solution-finding algorithm will hunt elsewhere. (Details about avoiding division by zero in g and other problems left as an exercise for the reader.)